# How to add a WPF Web browser in Child window of MahApps.Metro.Controls form

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, mahapps.metro

I don't know whether it is possible or not.

I have tried many different methods but I am unable to solve.

I have a MetroWindow WPF form (MetroHamburgerMenu). I wants to add one wpf child window as a web browser  to one of its control button.

The XAML for web browser as below:

```
<Grid
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

        <Grid>
            <DockPanel>
                <WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="50"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                </WebBrowser>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Fortunately, the child window is added, however the background is transparent so that the web page is not visible. I have added Google.com to web browser navigation.

Could you someone please guide how to correctly display the web page in child window?.

If question is not clear please let me know.

[MainForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Zsa.png)

Comment: Did you put any content into the web browser?  I don't see that in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I have that inside in my script.

`#Add View Plan child window
$ViewPlan   = $Form.FindName("Production_Plan")
$ProductionPlanXAML = LoadXaml($viewFolder + '\WebBrowser.xaml')
$ProductionPlanChildreader     = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $ProductionPlanXAML)
$ProductionPlan_Xaml     = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($ProductionPlanChildreader)
$WebBrowser = $ProductionPlan_Xaml.FindName("WebBrowser")

$WebBrowser.Navigate("https://Google.com")

$ViewPlan.Children.Add($ProductionPlan_Xaml)
`

Comment: Web browser navigation is working. When I move mouse on the white screen it shows Hyperlinks. Also when I am keeping mouse on google search box a small text shows as "Search". The Only problem with the transparency.

Comment: `[xml]$xaml=@"
   <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="$Title" Height="500" Width="700">
        <Grid>  <DockPanel>
                <WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30">
                </WebBrowser>  </DockPanel>
        </Grid>   </Window>
"@
#Add-Type -Name 'Windows.Markup.XamlReader'
#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$WebBrowser = $Form.FindName("WebBrowser")
$WebBrowser.Navigate("https://Google.com")
$Form.ShowDialog()`

Comment: The above code is working. I have used same xaml in MetroHamburgerMenu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer.

I have found the mistake why it was transparent. In the main form window AllowsTransparency property was set to True. Now I have change this property to False and I could see the web page visible.

It was very a silly mistake which I was unable to trace.